# JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, function

I am not able to move on to the next section since i could not understand how this works. For reference I will post the link.
  http://eloquentjavascript.net/1st_edition/chapter7.html

```
var roads = {};

function makeRoad(from, to, length) {
  function addRoad(from, to) {
    if (!(from in roads))
      roads[from] = [];
    roads[from].push({to: to, distance: length});
  }

  addRoad(from, to);
  addRoad(to, from);
}
```

I am totally lost to get the basic idea of this function. Anyone who is generous to help. Thank you in advance. you are always help me to unlock many concepts.

Comment: Help how? What is the question?

Comment: Basically, it makes roads. In two directions.

Comment: That link explains it nicely, what *specifically* is unclear to you?

Comment: I know it is for making roads and what is difficult for me is the way the function is constructed. the makeRoad and addRoad functions.

Comment: What do you mean by "basic idea", how it is structured syntactically? Or what it does?

Answer (score 1):

It works by defining a function inline (`addRoad`) and then calling it to add a road in each direction (`from` to `to` and then `to` to `from`).

`addRoad` maintains a data structure of roads:

```
"roads": [
    "fromLocation" : [ "destination1", "destination2" ],
    "fromLocation2" : [ "destination3" ]
]
```

`addRoad` first checks to see if the `from` location exists in the array of roads (that's the `if (!(from in roads))` clause. If it doesn't exist then it creates an empty array to store future destinations. It can then add the destination to that array.

To create my example data structure above I could call `addRoad` as follows:

```
addRoad('fromLocation', 'destination1');
addRoad('fromLocation', 'destination2');
addRoad('fromLocation2', 'destination3');
```

Comment: thank you simpleigh. you are the best than those who answer questions by question.